# How to find rows in a data frame with this criterion (with the use of Pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas, filtering

With the use of Pandas, I want to find rows in which there is only one column containing a specific value while the other columns of the same row are empty. In fact, I don't need the rows containing that specific value when other columns contain any value. Does Pandas offer any solution for this?

to clarify, take the table below as an example. I want to get row 2 and row 4 which have columns containing number 3 while the other two columns contain zero.

---

**Example df:**

| Data | column1 | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| data 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| data 2 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| data 3 | 0 | 4 | 3 |
| data 4 | 0 | 3 | 0 |

Comment: Could you please provide an example and can you show what you have tried?

Comment: Iterate through row. Get values of row in a tuple, check for the value you want to check and also check if other values are 0 or null. Then perform further

Comment: I put a table to give an example of what I intend to do. Thanks

Comment: Could you please also add the intended output?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
df=df.loc[:,['column1','column2','column3',]]
three=df.isin([3]).sum(axis=1)==1
zero=df.isin([0, None, np.nan]).sum(axis=1)==2
mask=three&zero
df.loc[mask,:]
```

---

**Explanation:**

This extract the relevent columns:

```
df=df.loc[:,['column1','column2','column3',]]
```

Next you have to make a Boolean mask for the rows:

```
three=df.isin([3]).sum(axis=1)==1 # the row contains one 3
zero=df.isin([0]).sum(axis=1)==2  # the row contains two 0's
mask=three&zero
```

Where the `mask` produces:

```
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool
```

`df.loc[mask,:]` produces the final result:

```
    column1 column2 column3
1   3   0   0
3   0   3   0
```